# How to make a table cell blank when the column class is float or double

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a `JTable` which model was extended to `AbstractTableModel`. It has 4 columns. First two columns hold string and last two columns hold double type data. The last 2 columns displays 0.0 when the data is Null;

**But I want to display it as blank when the value is null or 0; And when I will edit the cell and type any numerical value it will set double data type value with precision point.**

```
col1 || col2 || col3 || col4 
-----------------------------
aaa  || a1  || 250.00||
bb   || b1  ||       || 10.5
============================
```

A solution may be that to change in `getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)` method and return " " when columnIndex is 3 and 4. But it creates another problem. When I edit the cell it return String value and required to parse the string value to double at `setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)` method with `Double.parseDouble(value.toString());`

But I think it is not wise or correct to parse the string value to`Double`; I think `setCellEditor` may be a good solution. But I cant understand how to set a cell editor to double data type.

```
mytable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(???);
```

Could you give any solution.

Comment: Please check the [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) tutorial and especially the "Using Custom Renderers" section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the CellRenderer, not the CellEditor.

Read from "Concepts: Editors and Renderers" here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Thanks but not suitable for me, in fact I already read it before. I am not expecting guideline rather some code base solution related with my problem.

Comment: @IqbalHossain if you read what you have in bold in your question it seems that this is what you need. To implement a new `TableCellRenderer` that would treat null values as empty string. If this is not what you need perhaps you should re-phrase your question, because I have understood the same thing that Xabster has.

Answer (score 0):

At last I could solve my problem using following codes.

```
@Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        if (value.equals(Double.valueOf(0))){
            super.setValue("");        
        }
        else {
            DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)");        
            Number num = (Number)value;
            super.setValue(numberFormat.format(num));
        }

        return c;
    }
```

Comment: so the guideline (telling you to implement a custom _renderer_) helped after all :_)